# How to fix mercurial repository that contains very long file path more 260 characters

Tags: windows, mercurial

I have mercurial repository that contains file path more 260 characters.
If I try to clone to windows machine, i get error.
So I need to change file path in repository, but it won't help, because mercurial log store old changset with long path.
How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [ConvertExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) to create a new repository with the long pathnames renamed to shorter ones using the `--filemap` option, and then clone from that (see the section "Converting From Mercurial").  Note that you need to enable the convert extension in your `hgrc` first.

Example:

Create "filemap.txt":

```
rename some/really/long/path/name shorter/path
...
```

Then:

```
hg convert --filemap filemap.txt original_repo new_repo
hg clone new_repo [windows_repo]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I just rollback 3 revisions by
`code`
hg strip
`code`